# CGContextSetShadowWithColor puts shadows on top of the text casting the shadow

Tags: ios, text, core-graphics, shadow

I am using `CGContextSetShadowWithColor` and core graphics to draw shadowed text. The shadow appears, but it also seems to "muddy" the actual text itself which is casting the shadow (which should be pure white). It is as if it is casting the shadow on top of the text (but not quite).

Like this:

[image: Muddy text created with CGContextSetShadowWithColor]

If I redraw the text in the same position with shadowing off, I can overwrite the muddy text with clean white text, so it is a work-around, but I am wondering:

Am I am doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

```
    let shadowOffset : CGSize = CGSize (width: 4, height: 4)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 800, height: 200), false, 1.0)
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, 200);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 1.0)
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, shadowOffset, 5, UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor)

    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing (ctx, true)

    let attr:CFDictionaryRef = [
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]

    let line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(CFAttributedStringCreate(nil, "1234567890", attr))

    let bounds = CTLineGetBoundsWithOptions(line, CTLineBoundsOptions.UseOpticalBounds)

    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1)
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFillStroke)

    CGContextSetTextPosition(ctx, 100.0, 100.0)
    CTLineDraw(line, ctx)

    //Uncomment to clean-up text
    //CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, shadowOffset, 0, nil)
    //CGContextSetTextPosition(ctx, 100.0, 100.0)
    //CTLineDraw(line, ctx)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling to `CGContextSetTextDrawingMode`, set the drawing mode to `kCGTextFill`. To my understanding, the shadow you see is casted by the stroke of the text.

Comment: That was it. My stroke and fill are the same color, so it doesn't matter. Tried different colors and it didn't seem to work anyway.